# How to use `Series.interpolate` in pandas with the old values modified

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

The `interploate` method in `pandas` use the valid data to interpolate the `nan` values. However, it keeps the old valid data unchanged as the following codes.

Is there any way to use `interploate` method with the old values changed such that the series become smooth?

```
In [1]: %matplotlib inline
In [2]: from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline as spl
In [3]: import numpy as np
In [4]: import pandas as pd
In [5]: samples = { 0.0: 0.0, 0.4: 0.5, 0.5: 0.9, 0.6: 0.7, 0.8:0.3, 1.0: 1.0 }
In [6]: x, y = zip(*sorted(samples.items()))

In [7]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=np.linspace(0, 1, 31), columns=['raw', 'itp'], dtype=float)

In [8]: df1.loc[x] = np.array(y)[:, None]
In [9]: df1['itp'].interpolate('spline', order=3, inplace=True)
In [10]: df1.plot(style={'itp': 'b-', 'raw': 'rs'}, figsize=(8, 6))
```

[image]

```
In [11]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=np.linspace(0, 1, 31), columns=['raw', 'itp'], dtype=float)
In [12]: df2.loc[x, 'raw'] = y
In [13]: f = spl(x, y, k=3)
In [14]: df2['itp'] = f(df2.index)
In [15]: df2.plot(style={'itp': 'b-', 'raw': 'rs'}, figsize=(8, 6))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `Series.interpolate` with `method='spline'`, under the hood [Pandas uses
`interpolate.UnivariateSpline`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/common.py#L1721).

The spline returned by
[`UnivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html)
is not guaranteed to pass through the data points given as input [unless
`s=0`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline).
However, by default `s=None`, which uses a different smoothing factor and thus leads to a different result.

The `Series.interpolate` method **always** [fills in NaN
values](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/common.py#L1671)
without changing the non-NaN values. There is no way to make
`Series.interpolate` modify the non-NaN values. So, when `s != 0`, the result
produces jagged jumps.

So if you want the `s=None` (default) spline interpolation but without the
jagged jumps, as you've already found, you have to call `UnivariateSpline`
directly and overwrite all the values in `df['itp']`:

```
df['itp'] = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y, k=3)(df.index)
```

If you want a cubic spline that passes through all the non-NaN data points, then
use `s=0`

```
df['itp'].interpolate('spline', order=3, s=0, inplace=True)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate

samples = { 0.0: 0.0, 0.4: 0.5, 0.5: 0.9, 0.6: 0.7, 0.8:0.3, 1.0: 1.0 }
x, y = zip(*sorted(samples.items()))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=np.linspace(0, 1, 31), columns=['raw', 'itp'], dtype=float)
df1.loc[x] = np.array(y)[:, None]

df2 = df1.copy()
df3 = df1.copy()

df1['itp'].interpolate('spline', order=3, inplace=True)
df2['itp'] = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y, k=3)(df2.index)
df3['itp'].interpolate('spline', order=3, s=0, inplace=True)
for i, df in enumerate((df1, df2, df3)):
    df.plot(style={'itp': 'b-', 'raw': 'rs'}, figsize=(8, 6), ax=ax[i])
plt.show()
```

[image]